# Magento product visibility search not working in enterprise edition 1.14

Tags: magento

I was using Magento enterprise 1.14. I have added a product with visibility catalog,search. When i try to search the product on front end, the product included in search result but when i try to change the visibility to search and searches it, it does not included in search result. Can somebody help in this as i already wasted hours in this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow with indexing or is partial indexing running on your site and was the indexing completed.

Are your search listing being fetched from Solr or from Magento database.In case from Solr you need to make sure Solr was updated with changes which is generally when partial indexing indexes products in question.

If you make sure that partial indexing is working fine and everything is indexed( You might have to look into CL tables to confirm on this ) this issue should be gone.

Comment: I am not using Solr search and indexing is also done. I have a fresh magento ee 1.14 installation with only one product in store. Partial indexing is working fine too.

Comment: check flat table for entry of that product. Also you need to check price index table.

Comment: Entry is there in flat table as well as in catalog_product_index_price

Comment: try searching with some other parameter that will result in listing of this product.Probably one of the search table is populated with result for the keyword you are trying to search with.

Comment: I also tried with some other parameters as you suggested but issue is still apparent.

Comment: When i am changing visibility to catalog,search than it works perfect.

Comment: Why you want to remove visibility catalog from a product.

Comment: I want to include those product in search result having visibility as "search" as per client requirement.

Comment: Are you come up with a solution?

Comment: Need to analyse this further.Will get back soon.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue also. I have fixed this issue by some modification in below file.

> > app/code/core/Enterprise/Catalog/Model/Index/Action/Catalog/Category/Product/Refresh.php

Approx line no 810

find

```
array(
    Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH,
    Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG
)
```

and replace with

```
array(
        Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH,
        Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG,
        Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_SEARCH
    )
```

Hope, this will help you.

Cheers!